# How to groupby a dictionary and aggregate a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe 'df' with index 'Country' and a column 'Estimated Population'.
[image]

The index has 15 country names.
I also have a dictionary:

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
              'United States':'North America', 
              'Japan':'Asia', 
              'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
              'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
              'Canada':'North America', 
              'Germany':'Europe', 
              'India':'Asia',
              'France':'Europe', 
              'South Korea':'Asia', 
              'Italy':'Europe', 
              'Spain':'Europe', 
              'Iran':'Asia',
              'Australia':'Australia', 
              'Brazil':'South America'}
```

All the countries in the dictionary are present in the dataframe.
Using the given dictionary, I need to "group the Countries by Continent, then create a dateframe that displays the mean and std deviation for the estimated population of each country."

This is the code I tried:

```
df2=df.groupby(ContinentDict)['Estimated Population'].agg({'mean':np.mean,'std':np.std})
```

When I run this code I get the error "No numeric types to aggregate"

Then I tried the following code:

```
df2=pd.to_numeric(df.groupby(ContinentDict)['Estimated Population']).agg({'mean':np.mean,'std':np.std})
```

This gives me the error "Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)"

How can I eliminate these errors and get the database I need?

Comment: Include a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I edited the question it has a picture of the dataframe now.

Comment: What's the dtype of `Estimated Population` column?, you can check it by executing `df["Estimated Population"].dtype`.

Comment: @Harsha You need to add sample dataframe in terms of hardcode not picture.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma "dtype('O')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the **dtype** of the `Estimated Population` column before applying the `.agg` function.

Use:

```
df['Estimated Population'] = df['Estimated Population'].astype(float)
```

Or,

```
df['Estimated Population'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Estimated Population'])
```